# Merge two dataframes without duplicate rows

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have a `dataframeA`

```
ID-A  ID'-A   Type   Date 
1      2       A   08/2020
3      2       A   09/2020
3      6       A   09/2020
2      4       A   09/2020
2      8       A   12/2020
```

and a `dataframeB`

```
ID-B  ID'-B   Type   Date 
5      2       B   09/2020
6      3       B   10/2020
8      1       B   10/2020
4      10      B   11/2020
```

i want this output : iterate over DataframeB by date and if ID'-B = ID-A copy the row next

```
ID-A  ID'-A   Type   Date   ID-B  ID'-B  Type   Date
1      2       A   08/2020  8      1       B   10/2020
3      2       A   09/2020  6      3       B   10/2020
3      6       A   09/2020  Nan    Nan    Nan  Nan
2      4       A   09/2020  5      2       B   09/2020
2      8       A   12/2020  Nan    Nan     Nan  Nan
Nan    Nan    Nan   Nan     4      10      B   11/2020
```

I tried to use the merge with keys :

```
out = pd.merge(DataframeA ,DataframeB ,  how='left' , left_on =['ID-A'] ,  right_on =['ID'-B'])
```

but it give me a duplicate rows

```
ID-A  ID'-A   Type   Date   ID-B  ID'-B  Type   Date
1      2       A   08/2020  8      1       B   10/2020
3      2       A   09/2020  6      3       B   10/2020
3      6       A   09/2020  6      3       B   10/2020
2      4       A   09/2020  5      2       B   09/2020
2      8       A   12/2020  5      2       B   09/2020
Nan    Nan    Nan   Nan     4      10      B   11/2020
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to rename your second dataframes columns, otherwise you're going to end up with duplicate columns and the merge with suffix them with `_x` and `_y`.

So you need to rename your `dfb` column first.

Then you can use `duplicated` to select only the first records from `dfa` to merge on, then `concat` to add the duplicates back after the merge.

```
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'ID-A': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 "ID'-A": {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 6, 3: 4, 4: 8},
 'Type': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A'},
 'Date': {0: '08/2020',
  1: '09/2020',
  2: '09/2020',
  3: '09/2020',
  4: '12/2020'}})


dfb = pd.DataFrame({'ID-B': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 8, 3: 4},
 "ID'-B": {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 10},
 'Type': {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'B'},
 'Date': {0: '09/2020', 1: '10/2020', 2: '10/2020', 3: '11/2020'}})

dfb.columns = ['ID-B',"ID'-B",'Type-B','Date-B']


pd.concat([dfa[~dfa.duplicated(subset=['ID-A'])].merge(dfb, left_on=['ID-A'], right_on=["ID'-B"], how='left'),
           dfa[dfa.duplicated(subset=['ID-A'])]],axis=0)
```

Output

```
    ID-A    ID'-A   Type    Date    ID-B    ID'-B   Type-B  Date-B
0   1           2   A     08/2020   8.0      1.0    B       10/2020
1   3           2   A     09/2020   6.0      3.0    B       10/2020
2   2           4   A     09/2020   5.0      2.0    B       09/2020
2   3           6   A     09/2020   NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
4   2           8   A     12/2020   NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: but we dont have any duplicate row in dfa ? and there is Nan row  in ID-A  ID'-A   Type   Date

Comment: You have duplicates in the `ID-A` which is why your merge is breaking.